# Set “log4j1.compatibility” to a value of “true” in an ANT project

Tags: ant, log4j, log4j2

Our Project is ANT based and we are trying to migrate from log4j 1.X to log4j 2.x as immediate solution we wanna use **Log4j 1.x bridge** but for this we need to set the **log4j1.compatibility** to **true**  . But I am not sure how to set this system property to true in an ant script. Need help in understanding this.

Comment: Can you provide an example of Ant target, where you want to set this system property?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz  we have system configuration <sysproperty key="log4j.configuration" > to set our log4j configuration. I was wondering if we can have  similar system property <sysproperty key="log4j1.compatibility " value="true" > will work so that the  Log4j 1.x bridge can support this and use log4j1 xml files.

Comment: That should work, did you try it?BTW: `log4j1.compatibility` is only required if you don't specify `log4j.configuration`.